# What is the difference between "reflect on" and "recall"?

Tags: phrases

For example, I often "recall" or "reflect on" my schooldays.
Is there any difference? If not, which one is more common?

Comment: You should consult a few online dictionaries and then ask the question if their definitions do not make the difference clear.

Answer (score 3):

*Recall* means to remember a specific item of information from the past.

*Reflect on* means to think about an event or series of events that caused something, and learn from it or show devotion/respect to it.

Comment: Therefore, in my case, it seems  "reflect on" is more appropriate, because there are many events happened in my schooldays. Is it right?

Comment: I would say so.

Answer (score 0):

- Reflect (on): Learn from or regret/reminisce after something (especially an event) that you previously saw or experienced happened.
- Recall: Remember something that you previously saw or experienced.

While they have almost the same meaning, 'Reflect' has a meaning of **learn from** while 'Recall' does not.